# Improve performance of a foreach persist call with JPA

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, hibernate, jpa

We have a business logic something like this:

```
public class StuffLogic {
    @Autowired
    private Util util;
    // ...

    public void processStuffs() {
        // Simply returns a list of 50k objects
        List<Stuff> list = dao.getManyFilteredStuff();

        for (Stuff act : list) {
            act.setStatus(StatusEnum.SomeStatus);
        }

        util.mergeAll(list);
    }
}

public class Util {
    // ...

    @Transactional
    public void mergeAll(List<?> list) {
        for (Object o : entities) {
            entityManager.merge(o);
        }
    }
}
```

We have a lot of entities (~50 000) and would like to improve the performance (based on the preliminary measurements, we can process 1 000 entities per second at the moment).

Does any of you have any hints on that?

What we have tried so far:

- Multithreading. It seems if we use multithreaded execution and doing the processing, persisting in different threads, it won't really speed up the execution time but slows it down about the factor of 5. We're on Oracle, and maybe it uses table locking instead of row locking for the updates, so all the threads have to wait.
- Unfortunately, using one single bulk update is not an option, because we have many listeners introducing some magic in place which are not working with the single update statement.

Some tech details: we're using Oracle, JPA/Hibernate.

Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I assume the call to `persist` is inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, typo. Basically we have a utility function somewhere that calls persist() for each element and it is marked with @Transactional.

Comment: Plesae post some actual code as currently I have no clue about transactions, how many entity managers are involved are you using a single loop or multiple loops. There is too little information...

Comment: I would assume the loop is also in a transaction and that there is actually a single transaction. Having 5000 + 1 transactions isn't very fast, as starting/commit is slow. Use batches instead of single commits will speed up things, also shouldn't you be using `merge` instead of `persist` (the latter is for new entities).

Comment: As requested please use actual code not derived as what you now have cannot work (no arguments, method names don't match).

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for the updates. Persist was a typo, we're using merge(). There should be only 1 huge transaction on the merge() call.

Comment: no offense please, but if you really need performance then you should use pure SQL - avoid using JPA. There is no other option. You are reaching physical limitations, even if your DB was super-fast you would spend most of the time waiting for round-trips between app. and db. Your goal is to reduce number of round-trips. The problem is that JPA simply can not produce more complex query which will modify all data in a single shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do, as you are updating everything in one large go, the first level cache grows and grows. Which could increase the time it takes to do dirty checking.

So after x records (find the sweetspot) do a flush and clear on the entityManager.

```
public void mergeAll(List<?> list) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Object o : entities) {
        entityManager.merge(o);
        i++:
        if (i ^ 50 == 0) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManger.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can also instruct hibernate to batch statements for this you need to tweak your hibernate settings. First there is `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to enable batching.

```
 hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
```

This should reduce the amount of queries fired to oracle instead of 50 single queries it will be a single query with 50 entries.

If your modifications lead to both updates and inserts you might want to order them so that hibernate can group them together and use batch statements.

```
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updates=true
```

If you are using versioning you might also need to set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data` to `true`.

A nice post on these properties can be found [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the input! Let us play a bit with these settings and see how much it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can this article about batch processing http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Also maybe you can consider dynamically building of query like:

```
UPDATE stuff
SET status = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'status1'
            WHEN id = 2 THEN 'status2' 
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks, will take a look on that docs, seems promising. The update is not an option because there are listeners which won't be triggered otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `mergeAll` is executed in a separate transaction (otherwise there would be no need to call `merge` if the entities are already in persistence context), then you will have many database round trips (at least one for each entity) to fetch entities to merge.

One of the solutions is to read all those entities by a query (the same query you used to read the entities prior to processing or by using the construct `select e from entity where entity.id in (?, ?, ?, ...)`) and then merging them, because the entities will be in persistence context when they are merged.

You may want to combine this approach with batched flushing/clearing of persistence context for better memory management as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we'll inspect this idea as well. Looks a promising tip.